# Error: 'fields' parameter is required for this method

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

```
Google API: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The 'fields' parameter is required for this method. [400]
Errors[
Message[The 'fields' parameter is required for this method.] Location[fields - parameter] Reason[required] Domain[global]
]
```

I'm trying to use the About resource in the Google Drive API (.v3) and receiving an error I can't seem to resolve, that isn't answered in documentation. I've spent a few days researching to no avail and don't quite understand what the error message is telling me. New to using the API. :)

P. S. oRequest.Fields does not exist. Tried that too.

```
string result = "success";
try {
    About oRequest = driveService.About.Get().Execute();
    result = result + oRequest.User;
} catch (Exception e) {
    result = "Google API: " + e.Message;
}
textBox1.Text = result;
return result;
```

Updated: The code below is an improvement, but produces "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the result line... :\

```
AboutResource.GetRequest oRequest = driveService.About.Get();
oRequest.Fields = "user:displayName, user:permissionId, user:emailAddress";
About oResponse = oRequest.Execute();
result = oResponse.User.DisplayName + " | " + oResponse.User.PermissionId + " | " + oResponse.User.EmailAddress;
```

Comment: the answer is in the question. Add `fields=*` to the About.get

Comment: See updated code.

Comment: set fields to * which means everything. Then dump the result object to see what it contains.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can also request a full User object `Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.User`, if you use "user" as field.

For example:

```
var request = service.About.Get();
request.Fields = "user";
var user = request.Execute().User;
```

Instead of getting a full response object `Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.About`

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
string result = "success";
try {
    AboutResource.GetRequest oRequest = driveService.About.Get();
    oRequest.Fields = "*";
    About oResponse = oRequest.Execute();
    result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oResponse);
} catch (Exception e) {
    result = "Google API: " + e.InnerException;
}
textBox1.Text = result;
return result;
```